# MS Excel "subscript out of range" when copy worksheets to new Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet, office-2013

I have a MS Excel workbook containing many worksheets.

Users enter data in one of the worksheets and then click a button which runs VBA code. Based on conditions derived from user entered data, I need to create a new Workbook containing copies of some of the worksheets.

The code then iterates (loop) through the worksheets in the source Workbook and add the names of the relevant worksheets to a string...

```
Dim worksheetsToCopy As String

worksheetsToCopy = worksheetsToCopy & """" & "Admin Tab" & """" & ", "
```

After the loop completed I inspect the variable with
    Debug.Print worksheetsToCopy 
which gives me the following output in the Immediate Window:
"Admin Tab", "Home Tab", "Dashboard",

Then I strip-out the last "," with

```
worksheetsToCopy = Mid(worksheetsToCopy, 1, InStrRev(worksheetsToCopy, ",") - 1)
```

Then, when I try to copy the worksheets contained in the variable worksheetsToCopy with the following line of code, I get the runtime error 9 - Subscript out of range:

```
Sheets(Array(worksheetsToCopy)).Copy
```

However, when I run the same instruction but manually enter the tabs names in quotes and with commas as below, it works fine:

```
Sheets(Array("Admin Tab", "Home Tab", "Dashboard")).Copy
```

Why do I get the runtime error 9 - "Subscript out of range" error with the first statement.

What am I doing wrong or missing?
Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: Your code is equivalent to  `Sheets(Array("""Admin Tab"", ""Home Tab"", ""Dashboard""")).Copy`, not `Sheets(Array("Admin Tab", "Home Tab", "Dashboard")).Copy`. See Dawid answer for how to build an array from a string.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are creating a double quoted string. Try to create a normal string with names separated by comma and split it to an actual array, for example:
"Admin Tab,Home Tab,Dashboard"
Once you get your string, remove the last comma and use it like this for the sheets array copy:

```
'Add a string array variable
Dim sheetArray() As String

'Remove the last , from the string of Worksheets to copy
worksheetsToCopy = Mid(worksheetsToCopy, 1, InStrRev(worksheetsToCopy, ",") - 1)

'Create the array from your string
sheetArray = Split(worksheetsToCopy, ",")

'And copy the sheets
Sheets(sheetArray).Copy
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback Dawid.
I tried it as you described, but I still get the exact same error...
Any other ideas perhaps?

Comment: Could you please post the rest of your code? Could be something with the sheet name as that error comes in when the object is not set.

Comment: I found the missing piece, the removal of the last , from the string of worksheetsToCopy string.

I added it to your post, to help people in future that may have the same issue.

I'll also post the whole set of code in my original post.

Thanks for your assistance Dawid, much appreciated.

Comment: Good to hear that! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to the error described in the topic.

[The worksheet in MS Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9NMH.png)
The code that executes when the user clicks the "Create new Workbook" button:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ButtonCreateWorkbook_Click()
'
' ButtonCreateClientWorkbookk_Click Macro
' This Macro creates a new workbook containing specific worksheets based on the selection
' that are set in the "Control" worksheet of the Workbook
'
Dim strWorksheetsToCopy As String
Dim wbSourceWorkbook As Workbook
Dim strControlSheet As String
Dim iRowStart As Integer
Dim iRowEnd As Integer
Dim strWorksheetColumn As String
Dim strSwitchColumn As String
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim strSheetArray() As String

Set wbSourceWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

strControlSheet = "Control"
wbSourceWorkbook.Sheets(strControlSheet).Activate
strWorksheetColumn = "B"   'this variable indicates which iRow contains the Worksheet names
iRowStart = 2           'this value must set to the iRow number where the FIRST Worksheet Name occurs in Column A
'this value must be set to the iRow number where the LAST Worksheet Name occurs in Column B
iRowEnd = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
strSwitchColumn = "C"     'this column must be set to the value of the "On/Off Switch" column on the "Control_ShowHide" worksheet.

'This section of code controls which worksheets must be copied and add the name of the worksheet to the string
For iRow = iRowStart To iRowEnd
    'Check if the worksheet must be copied
    If wbSourceWorkbook.Sheets(strControlSheet).Range(strSwitchColumn & iRow).Value > 0 Then
        strWorksheetsToCopy = strWorksheetsToCopy & wbSourceWorkbook.Sheets(strControlSheet).Range(strWorksheetColumn & iRow).Value & ","
    End If
Next iRow
Debug.Print strWorksheetsToCopy

'Remove the last , from the string
strWorksheetsToCopy = Mid(strWorksheetsToCopy, 1, InStrRev(strWorksheetsToCopy, ",") - 1)

'Transpose the String to a string array
strSheetArray = Split(strWorksheetsToCopy, ",")

'Create the new Workbook with the relevant sheets
wbSourceWorkbook.Sheets(strSheetArray).Copy

End Sub
```